# How do I get a command linked to one program run another program?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ffmpeg, python

Kind of a weird situation here. I use a software package called OpenCV which installs a dependency called FFMpeg located at the following path.

```
/root/miniconda3/bin/ffmpeg
```

So, whenever I run the command `ffmpeg`, it runs the program located at that address.

However, I don't want to use this build of `ffmpeg`, but rather another build located at the following path.

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

Not only do I want `ffmpeg` to point to the right one, I also want [Python subprocess calls](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to point to the right `ffmpeg`, so just using bash aliases won't work. I know there's ways around Python's subprocess function that make it respect aliases, but the problem is that I'm using a 3rd party module that makes the subprocess call to FFMpeg, hence I need the `ffmpeg` command to refer to `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` for all intents and purposes.

I tried using a symlink but that didn't do anything.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: `I tried using a symlink` – How exactly?

Comment: The point of anaconda/miniconda is really to make sure to always have a particular version of a dependency in some environment. If you want your local ffmpeg instead of that particular version, I'd install OpenCV not via anaconda/miniconda, but directly.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski ln -s /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg ffmpeg

Comment: @dirkt understood but I actually need ffmpeg for another thing unrelated to OpenCV. It just so happens both programs require a different build of ffmpeg. Although /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg contains a superset of features in the one that shipped with OpenCV so I don’t suspect swapping them out will cause a problem.

Comment: So what's stopping you from using OpenCV as e.g. provided by your distro, instead of using miniconda? Or does your distro have a miniconda OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

Might be dangerous but this seems to do the trick.

```
ln -sf /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg /root/miniconda3/bin/ffmpeg
```

Comment: And it'll work only until the next miniconda install. During which the `ffmpeg` installed there might overwrite the `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`, depending on how miniconda does the installs. Which would probably cause an interesting bughunt, if it happened.